# Bootstrap 3 - Row with columns of equal height has evenly spacing columns (images) instead of left align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have set the columns in the row to the same height and now the columns are filling the row (i.e., if the row only has two columns [images] then they are spaced wide apart - evenly spaced to fill the row.) I would like columns left aligned.

CSS:

```
.equal {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='row equal col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 container-fluid'>
    <div class='col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-6'>
        <a href='#' onclick='selectPersonFunction</a>
            <img src=image width='60' style='border-style: none' alt='person image' />
        </a>
        <div class='caption class='col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-6'>
            <p>name</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: could u please upload proper working code? your code is not working.

Comment: please add the running code and you can add `justify-content:flex-start` @Glyn

Comment: This resolved my issue.